# When to use @Inject in angular 2?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

When I want to inject a service written by myself I use the `@Inject` decorator:

```ts
export class ScheduleComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(ConnectionsApi) private connectionsApi: ConnectionsApi ) { }
}
```

However if I use a service provided by Angular like `Http` this is not necessary:

```ts
export class ConnectionsApi {

    constructor(protected http: Http) {}
}
```

Why is thid different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ConnectionsApi` is a class and the provider you want to get a value injected from is registered for this class, then you don't need `@Inject()`

For all other cases you need `@Inject()`.

- You can't register a provider for primitive types like `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `Object` because they are not specific enough.
- You can't register a provider for an interface type because they are not available at runtime.

```ts
{provide: 'myStringToken': useValue: 123}
...
constructor(@Inject('myStringToken) private someConfig:number) {}
```

```ts
{provide: 'myStringToken': useClass: MyConfigurationClass}
...
constructor(@Inject('myStringToken) private someConfig:MyConfigurationInterface) {}
```

```ts
{provide: someOpaqueToken : useClass: MyConfigurationClass}
...
constructor(@Inject(someOpaqueToken) private someConfig:MyConfigurationInterface) {}
```

```ts
{provide: someOpaqueToken : useClass: MyClassThatImplementsX}
...
constructor(@Inject(someOpaqueToken) private someConfig:X) {}
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html